# Difference between &#x0D; and &#xD;

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, line-breaks

I need to parse some text/xml files I get from different sources. Now I have found some problems with line breaks.

In some files i get `&#x0D;` as line break, in some others i get only `&#xD;`.
Now our `Delphi XE 2` has some problems with `&#xD;`, it is not imported correctly.

For example:
1. `City&#x0D;&#x0A;State`
Result of import:

> City
>   State

2. `City&#xD;&#xA;State`
   Result of import:

> City&&State

Why does this occur and how to solve it?

Comment: Indy write spaces as a string like `#$D`. It looks quite the same. I think that you have no other choice that string substitution like `StringReplace(your_text_xml, '&#xD;', #13, [rfReplaceAll])`

Comment: I already thought about that workaround, but still hoped for some cleaner solution ;-)

Comment: Are you using a XML parser?

Comment: I use a ClientDataset and load the xml from a stream.

Comment: @fantaghirocco `#$D` is Pascal and is not XML. Here we are talking about XML numeric character references. Your `StringReplace` is no good. You'll collect text in `CDATA` sections too. I suggest that you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @DavidH oops I missed `<![CDATA[`! My bad

Comment: No, @whosrdaddy wanted to know how you were parsing the XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between these two XML texts. `&#x0D;` specifies the same character as `&#xD;`. Likewise for `&#x0A;` and `&#xA;`.

Your XML parser is broken and the solution is to either fix it or replace it.

Comment: Doesn't TXMLDocument of Delphi use MSXML?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I think it allows for different XML parsers, but on Windows by default you get MSXML. My guess is that the user is not using a real parser.