# Xpath Converts Char(13) Incorrectly

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

It looks like my query is converting `char(13)` wrong? If it isn't wrong can someone please explain this?

Query:

```
;with CTE1 as 
    (
        select 
            Product
            , (select t.* for xml raw('row'), type) as Data
        from 
            [PIM].[dbo].[MasterFeatures] as t
    )
, CTE2 as 
    (
        select
             Product,
             F.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as Field,
             F.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Data
             , GETDATE() AS createdDate
        from 
            CTE1 as c
            outer apply c.Data.nodes('row/@*') as F(C)
    )
select * 
from CTE2 x
WHERE x.Field<>'Product'
```

result with issue pointed out:

[image]

I thought `CHAR(13)` was supposed to be:

```
  '&#x0D;'
```

Comment: @Larnu I believe OP wants to know the difference  "&#x0D;" vs "&#xD;"

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I guess that would help. I didnt know there was a difference?

Comment: looks like this link kind of explains it. good to know i guess but it doesnt give me neough detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911440/difference-between-x0d-and-xd

Comment: You're right, @LukaszSzozda. The image (rather than a `text` version) didn't help for readability due the small size of the font. I didn't realise that were different.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry I guess I shouldve zoomed in more :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML allows flexibility in how numeric character references are presented. The following representations are completely equivalent:

```
&#xD; &#x0D; &#x000D; &#x00000000D; &#xd; &#x0d; &#13; &#00000000013;
```

If you care which of these is generated, then that means that the consumer of your data is not a conformant XML parser. Sadly it's quite common for people to try to parse XML "by hand" without even reading the XML specification first, so this is a not uncommon problem.

This has nothing to do with XPath by the way. The XPath processor doesn't serialize its result; some other bit of software is doing that.

Comment: Awesome, this is great information. Now that I know there is flexibility in the correct outputs I can spend less time researching things. I should also read the XML specification - this issue arose due to my experimenting with SQL Server's xml options, and if I am going to use them, I guess I should learn the basics.